# UI Appearance testing tool?

Tags: user-interface, testing, automation, uiappearance

I am looking for tools to web applications UI testing. I know that there are many tools like Selenium and similar, but I am looking something for testing UI appearance, not UI behavior. I do not want to test if correct form shows in correct moment. I would like to test charts, graphics and animations.

**Example**
Let assume that I have web application with complex animations created using [d3.js](http://d3js.org/). I would like to test appearance with accuracy at the level of individual pixels: size, distance, colors of individual elements, transitions time and even singular frames.

I do not know if it is sensible approach? Do you know of such a tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) may help you. This tool is based on image recongnition.